# How to validate multiple IP addresses as well as IPv6 using regex in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc

In my project, I am able to validate IP addresses like this:

```
function (value, element) {
  var octet = '(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])';
  var ip = '(?:' + octet + '\\.){3}' + octet;
  var ipRE = new RegExp('^' + ip + '$');
  return (ipRE.test(value));
}
```

Currently, it's accepting single IPv4 version addressses. I want to accept multiple IPv4/IPv6 version format too.

Example:

```
'0:0:0:0:0:ffff:192.1.56.10,172.30.60.1,fe80:41b2:41b2:935c:b113:da1a'
```

I am using the jQuery.validator API to perform validation.

Please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code that i have used to accept both IPv6 and Ipv4 versions in jquery.

```
 function checkipv6(str) {
            var perlipv6regex = "^\s*((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,2})|:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,3})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,4})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,5})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,6})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(:(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,7})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:)))(%.+)?\s*$";
            var aeronipv6regex = "^\s*((?=.*::.*)(::)?([0-9A-F]{1,4}(:(?=[0-9A-F])|(?!\2)(?!\5)(::)|\z)){0,7}|((?=.*::.*)(::)?([0-9A-F]{1,4}(:(?=[0-9A-F])|(?!\7)(?!\10)(::))){0,5}|([0-9A-F]{1,4}:){6})((25[0-5]|(2[0-4]|1[0-9]|[1-9]?)[0-9])(\.(?=.)|\z)){4}|([0-9A-F]{1,4}:){7}[0-9A-F]{1,4})\s*$";

            var regex = "/" + perlipv6regex + "/";
            return (/^\s*((([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){7}([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){6}(:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}|((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){5}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,2})|:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3})|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){4}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,3})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4})?:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){3}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,4})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,2}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){2}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,5})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,3}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}:){1}(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,6})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,4}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:))|(:(((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){1,7})|((:[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,4}){0,5}:((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|1\d\d|[1-9]?\d)){3}))|:)))(%.+)?\s*$/.test(str));
}



function (value, element) 
{

            var returnvalue;
            alert("IPcheck " + value);
            var result = value.split(",");

            for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

                var octet = '(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])';

                if (result[i].split(":").length == 1) {
                    var ip = '(?:' + octet + '\\.){3}' + octet;
                    var ipRE = new RegExp('^' + ip + '$');
                    returnvalue = ipRE.test(result[i]);

                }
                else {
                    returnvalue = checkipv6(result[i]);
                }
                // var octet= '([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])'
                //var octet = '(?2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?).(?2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?).(?2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?).(?2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?)'
                //                var ip = '(?:' + octet + '\\.){3}' + octet;
                //                var ipRE = new RegExp('^' + ip + '$');
                if (returnvalue == false) {
                    return returnvalue;
                }
            }
            return returnvalue;
        },
        "<br/>Please enter a Valid IP Address"
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to split the input on commas, then parse each part: find out if the address is IPv4 or IPv6, then use the proper regex for it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Regex sometime back useful for IP address validation

(?2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?).(?2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?).(?2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?).(?2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]|[01]?\d\d?)

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it does not helps

Comment: Could please share the any links for that

Comment: This regular expression only does IPv4. Combining 4 and 6 is doable, but tedious. I'll write some sort of a start for it in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: works for both v4 and v6 in the same function. Drawback: relies on PHP5.

```
<?php
function checkIP($IPaddr) {
     $packetNot = inet_pton($IPaddr);
     if ($packetNot === FALSE) return false;
     if (inet_ntop($packetNot) === FALSE) return false;
     return true;
} ?>
```

Comment: What IPv6 address did you try?

Comment: fe80:41b2:41b2:935c:b113:da1a

Comment: Nevermind regular expressions - about to edit my answer with something much more reliable, which works for both v4 and v6.